# Arguments against idealism / arguments against materialism

Tags: idealism, materialism

Are there any counter-argument to these arguments against idealism on the one hand, materialism in the other?

(1) Argument against idealism.

What is the relationship between idealists and their bodies?
When an idealist suffers from sleep loss, can he use his mind to make disappear, his lack of energy, irritation/nervousness, and muscle tension, that is, the physical symptoms associated with sleep loss? Indeed, if reality is all about representation, then one change one representation by creating another representations.

Could say similar thing with the side effects of a vaccine, or the symptoms of diabete, etc.

(2) Argument against materialism.

Experimental psychology showed that an efficient way that people use to regulate their emotions is to reframe their understanding of the situation which triggers the emotion.
For instance, when somebody jumps the line at the supermarket, which might annoy him, in order to regulate the anger, he could reframe the understanding of the situation by considering the fact, for instance, that he is not that much in a hurry, or that the person jumping the line might have personal problems, etc.

Is it an argument against materialism? Indeed, in this case, this is the representation of a situation which is primary.

Comment: Philosophical idealism/materialism are not about one's mind having or not having powers over matter. Primality concerns the nature of reality at the fundamental level and "ideal" and "material" aspects of everyday life, as used colloquially, are irrelevant to that.

Comment: @Conifold "Primality concerns the nature of reality at the fundamental level and "ideal" and "material" aspects of everyday life, as used colloquially, are irrelevant to that." I didn't understand this sentence

Comment: Your arguments concern "mind over matter" as used in everyday life, not what idealism and materialism mean in philosophy.

Comment: @Conifold I thought idealism/materialism is about what constitutes reality. Why "one's mind having or not having powers over matter" isn't part of reality? Reality is about things interacting one another

Comment: They would be part of reality, if they exist, but existence or not of such powers is an empirical question, and any answer to it will be consistent with most forms of both idealism and materialism. They disagree on how to interpret mind and matter fundamentally, not on how they manifest empirically.

Comment: "but existence or not of such powers is an empirical question" Why is it an empirical question more than the interpretation of mind and matter? What do we interpret if we only interpret intert entities of reality, be them made of mind of matter?